# Is it possible to print without using the print function in Python?

Tags: python, printing, stdout

I wondered whether it is possible to print (for example a string) in Python without the `print` function. This can be done by a command or by some trick.

For example, in C there are `printf` and `puts`.

Can someone show me a way to print or to deny this possibility?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Are you trying to make a function call instead of using the `print` statement?

Comment: Just like C, Python has multiple functions that default to printing to stdout. Just like C, Python documents all of those functions. Do you have an actual question, or are you just too lazy to read the tutorial and/or documentation and hoping people will telepathically guess what you want to do, read it for you, and write your code for you?

Comment: @GamesBrainia I just want to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sys.stdout.write("hello world\n")
```

Comment: the argument given to _write_  here **must** be **string.**

Answer (score 3):

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("hello")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
sys.stdout.write()
```

Sometimes I find `sys.stdout.write` more convenient than `print` for printing many things to a single line, as I find the ending comma syntax of `print` for suppressing the newline inconvenient.